# Show that $a^{2001} \equiv a \pmod {1000}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

> Suppose $a$ is a positive integer which is coprime to 10. Show that $$a^{2001} \equiv a \pmod {1000}$$

I know it has something to do with the Fermat-Euler theorem.

$\phi(1000) = 400$ and $a^{400}\equiv 1 \pmod {1000}$

However, I do not know how to proceed from here to show the congruence

Comment: If $a^{400}\equiv1$, then what about $a^{2000}$? and then what about $a^{2001}$?

Comment: Yes but 1000 is not a prime number, so I'm not sure how Fermat's little theorem can be applied here?

Comment: Who said anything about Fermat's little theorem? Look – how are $a^{400}$ and $a^{2000}$ related? If you know $a^{400}$ (and, you do), how can you use that relation to get $a^{2000}$?

Comment: Ahhhh yes. $a^{2000} ≡ a^{5(400)} ≡ 1$ and $a^{2001} ≡ a^{2000}a ≡ 1a ≡a$  

Thank you so much!

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

$a^{2000}≡a^{5\cdot400}=\left(a^{400}\right)^5≡1 (\mod 1000)$ therefore $^{2001}≡^{2000}≡[1]≡$

Comment: Tip: you can use `\pmod` to automatically get proper spacing on the modulo symbol: $a\equiv b\pmod{c}$

Answer (score 1):

As $1000=2^35^3$

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html)

$\lambda(5^32^3)=100,5^3$ will divide $a^n-1$  if $100|n$ and $(a,10)=1$